# Notification if review is available

Tags: feature-request, review

I know there is a notification if there is 3 or more review jobs available, where a brown square is shown (it's not even accurate), but isn't a notification for every review job available better? Even better, if there is a number showing the number of jobs available, all us reviewers will not have to go to the review page to check for review jobs, but instead, wait for the number appear.

It is a lot easier for non-mods to see what is needed for review. So why not? What do you think?

Comment: Just gain access to 10k tools...

Comment: @nicael: How does this show you pending reviews when there are fewer?

Comment: 10k tools show notifications for 10k specific review tasks